# C# - ORA-06550:wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DOPROCESS'

Tags: c#, asp.net, plsql, oracle11g

**EDIT: Please See Post #2**

I have scoured the threads here and I cannot figure out why I am receiving an ORA-06550 message.

The PL/SQL processes in Oracle without error.

The stored PROC receives 5 parameters and I am attemtping to output a single NUMBER parameter for exception handling.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

**PL/SQL**

```
PROCEDURE DoProcess( ocn IN WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY.CHECK_NO%TYPE,
                     oca IN WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY.AMOUNT%TYPE,
                     ecn IN WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY.CHECK_NO%TYPE,
                     eca IN WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY.AMOUNT%TYPE,
                     usr IN WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY.OVERRIDDEN_USER_ID%TYPE,
                     errCode OUT NUMBER )
AS
BEGIN
    Initialize( ocn, oca, ecn, eca, usr );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ocn: ' || ocn || CHR(10) ||
                         'oca: ' || oca || CHR(10) ||
                         'ecn: ' || ecn || CHR(10) ||
                         'eca: ' || eca || CHR(10) ||
                         'usr: ' || usr);
    IF IsValid( bsa_rec.CHECK_NO, errCode ) THEN UpdateProc;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('errCode: ' || errCode);
    END IF;
END DoProcess;
```

**C#**

```
public Int32 BankDataExceptionsDoProcess(string ckNo, string ckAmt, string checkNo, string checkAmt, string user)
    {
        Int32 errCode = 0;

        ckNo  = ckNo.Trim();
        double dblCkAmt = double.Parse(ckAmt.Trim());
        checkNo = checkNo.Trim();
        double dblCheckAmt = double.Parse(checkAmt.Trim());
        int uid = int.Parse(user);


        object obj = null;

        if (DBC == null)
            DBC = new DBConn();

        DBC.ExecutePackage(Vars.pkgBankDataExceptions,
                           out obj,
                           new ParameterDirection[] { ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Output },
                           new object[] { ckNo, dblCkAmt, checkNo, dblCheckAmt, uid, errCode }
                          );

        return errCode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an existing variable for the OUTPUT parameter in ADO.NET.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("OutputParam", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Then reference it after execution:

```
if(cmd.Parameters["OutputParam"] != null)
{
   int returnValue = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["OutputParam"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck, I see what you mean, I ended up figuring it out. I know this post is late but I was reviewing some old posts and this deserves an upvote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a small pice of code. It appears that the default out object contains all strings regardless of the oracle datatype.

Here is the missing pice of code:

```
errCode = int.Parse(obj.ToString());
```

The entire C# method:

```
public int BankStmntExceptionsDoProcess(string ckNo, string ckAmt, string checkNo, string checkAmt, string user)
    {
        int errCode = 0;;

        ckNo     = ckNo.Trim();
        ckAmt    = ckAmt.Trim();
        checkNo  = checkNo.Trim();
        checkAmt = checkAmt.Trim();
        user     = user.Trim();

        object obj = null;

        if (DBC == null)
            DBC = new DBConn();

        DBC.ExecutePackage(Vars.pkgBankStatementProcessing,
                           out obj,
                           new ParameterDirection[] { ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Input,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Output,
                                                    },
                           new object[] { ckNo, ckAmt, checkNo, checkAmt, user, errCode }
                           );

        errCode = int.Parse(obj.ToString());

        return errCode;
    }
```